# In Laravel while Seeding tables it throw error: with property [id] does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-seeding

I can't seed table with factory(num)->create().

```
$user = User::factory(10)->create();
```

It is show me error message :
[image]

but  I can seed the table with this statement

```
$user = User::create([ 'name' => 'noraddin','email' => 'noordeen@gmail.com', 'password' => 'nor1234']);
```

Can you help with seeding by factory() method, so I don't need to entering data by hand for testing stuff?

And this is my UserFactory class

```
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = User::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name(),
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail(),
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }
}
```

and this is migarate file of user

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id()->autoIncrement();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the error? Could you show us the **complete** error stack trace in a text format instead of an image?

Comment: If you try to do anything with `$user = User::factory(10)->create();`, you'll likely need to use a Loop. `$user` would be a Collection of 10 `User` Factory instances. Like if you did `$user->id`, you'd get that error. But if you did `foreach($user as $u)`, then `$u->id` would be 1 through 10. That is all speculation, since you didn't show which line of code caused that error, but I suspect you tried to do something with `$user` after the definition.

Comment: Your 2nd example, `$user = User::create([ 'name' => 'noraddin', 'email' => 'noordeen@gmail.com', 'password' => 'nor1234']);` works, since `$user` is a single `User` instance, not a Collection. Calling `$user->id` would return `1` (or whatever the `id` is for that single record).